# Assigning a checkbox to each row in a pandas df using ipywidgets

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have a pandas df and I am trying to assign a separate checkbox using ipywidgets to each row of the dataframe. I am creating a jupyterlab UI and my end goal is for a user to be able to look through the table, select true or false on the records they want, hit submit and then a backend operation will be performed using the data from the records whose checkbox is selected.

I am fairly new to ipywidgets so I haven't been able to get far. If there is an easier way to do this outside of using a pandas df, I'm open to that as well. I actually get the data in JSON format before turning it into a df so if that would be easier to use in this scenario, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while i never found a way to do this with pandas. All the functionality I needed and more can be found in the qgrid library.

https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid